# how to parametrize ui input via subprocess and retain a ui input method

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, user-input

There are two scripts
File_Move.py - for a dictionary of network paths if a file has a greater modify date then a locally stored dictionary then it will copy the file from network to local folder.

File_Decrypt.py - There are two user input requests:

1. script will check of gnupg keyrings need to be updated based on last modified date of local user pgp keyrings (if PGP Date > GNUPG Date ; update?).
2. Ask user what the directory of the decryption should be

```
if gnupg_key_automation(uflag)==1:
        print("\n\nWould you like to update your GPG Keys?")
        ui=input()
        #updating source pgp key if necessary

        if str.lower(ui) == "yes":
                print("...Updating...")
                update_gnupg_keys(ui)
        else:
                print("...Moving..Forward...")
```

```
#Get User input of directory with files wanting to review
print("\n\nPlease input directory of encrypted files\n Only able to use currently loaded keys")
ui=input()

if str(ui) == 'home':
    ui = "{}".format(home)

if os.path.isdir(ui) == True:
        print("Thank you for folder path: "+str(ui))
else:
        print("Please provide another input")

os.chdir(ui) #change directory to what was inputted
```

I attempted this answer and others similar, but it still returns the UI prompt and waits for user input
[program input redirected via python subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131637/program-input-redirected-via-python-subprocess)

If wanting to call the file_decrypt.py at the end of File_Move.py; what is the optimal method. Retaining the ability to manually call the File_Decrypt.py script independent of the file move?
Based on answers and reading I thought that sys.args[1] might work, but all attempts stop and return the prompt and wait for the input().